# htaccess for framework MVC, unlock folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory-structure

I have a problem with the file probably htaacess.

```
### htaccess ###

Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404
ErrorDocument 403 /error/403
```

The file works well but does not provide security when my normal web address is : localhost/mvc/index.php or localhost/mvc/index.php or localhost/mvc/post/view/22

where the post is controller everything works well.
the problem appears when my web address contains a folder + file .

localhost/mvc/models/post_model.php

localhost/mvc/public/layout.php

localhost/mvc/images/testimg.png

localhost/mvc/config/db.php

(it's all a folder / file, for example, you can now open the database configuration file)
when I open the file I should get an error , because such files contain configuration and things like that.
my index.php file looks like this:

```
### index.php ###

<?php
$on = 1;
if ($on == 1) {
    error_reporting(1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
}
require 'libs/bootstrap.php';
require 'libs/Controller.php';
require 'libs/Model.php';
require 'libs/Database.php';
require 'libs/Session.php';
require 'libs/View.php';
require 'libs/Jyll.php';
require 'config/db.php';
Session::init();
$bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
```

mainly the result is to be the files attached by require , include and something were active and open in every other way , crashes or redirect 403 error on the above page from mistake.
I would like to access to everything , had only the index.php file in the root

Comment: Well if you just want index.php in the root, the obvious solution would be to move the rest of your code above the web root, right?

Comment: are done so from the start page for just index and the rest located in subfolders , such as model , config , view , public , controller , etc .
when we enter in the / var / www / index.php MVC only see .htaccess and folders and folders that now has access to only be index.php and when someone alone in a web address typed this folder is to be error

Comment: Nothing about this has any connection to MVC architectural pattern.